# Flutter/Firebase: firebase_auth/channel-error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

im trying to make an app using flutter and firebase. When testing it, users can sign up with email/pw, and login but when i try to reset the password i get the following Error:

> I/flutter ( 4590): [firebase_auth/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel.

This is my current code for pw resetting:

```
Future passwordreset() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _emailController.text.trim());
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

```
CustomFormButton(
                            isLoading: _isLoading,
                            innerText: 'Reset Password',
                            onTap: () {
                              passwordreset();
                            },
                          ),
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Code is presented above